# PHP PDO statements similar to mysql_fetch_row($query, MYSQL_ASSOC))

Tags: php, html, mysql, pdo

I am trying to fetch query results so i can use the data from mysql as variables on my page

here in the given code i have hardcoded the hotel value as 105 but i am trying to get the value from an other page as get .

```
 $ratedID =$_GET['ratedhotel'];
```

Here the body of my page is embedded under while.but the page is always empty.and this is what i have at the moment.

```
$hotel=$database->query('SELECT * FROM rate WHERE HotelID=:hotel ');
$database->bind(':hotel', '105');
$hotel->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
while($r = $hotel->fetch())
```

Below Is what i had before.

```
 //$query = $db->query("SELECT * from rate WHERE        HotelId='$ratedhotelID'");
   //while($hotel = mysql_fetch_row($query, MYSQL_ASSOC))
```

I have some defined functions which I got as a library to use.

```
   <?php
    class Database{
    private $host=DB_HOST;
    private $user=DB_USER;
    private $pass=DB_PASS;
    private $dbname=DB_NAME;
    private $stmt;
    private $dbh;
    private $error;

    public function __construct()
    {
    // Set DSN
    $dsn = 'mysql:host=' . $this->host . ';dbname=' . $this->dbname;
    // Set options
    $options = array(
    PDO::ATTR_PERSISTENT    => true,
    PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE       => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION
    );
    // Create a new PDO instanace
       $this->dbh = new PDO($dsn, $this->user, $this->pass, $options);

    }



    public function query($query){
        $this->stmt = $this->dbh->prepare($query);
    }



    public function bind($param, $value, $type = null){
        if (is_null($type)) {
            switch (true) {
                case is_int($value):
                    $type = PDO::PARAM_INT;
                    break;
                case is_bool($value):
                    $type = PDO::PARAM_BOOL;
                    break;
                case is_null($value):
                    $type = PDO::PARAM_NULL;
                    break;
                default:
                    $type = PDO::PARAM_STR;
            }
        }
        $this->stmt->bindValue($param, $value, $type);
    }

    public function execute(){
        return $this->stmt->execute();
    }

    public function resultset(){
        $this->execute();
        return $this->stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    }


    public function single(){
        $this->execute();
        return $this->stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    }

    public function rowCount(){
        return $this->stmt->rowCount();
    }


    }
```

I am not sure and am new to PDO .Any help will be much appreciated.

Jai

**UPDATE**

I made Changes to php and the code is like below:

```
$database= new Database();
$database->query('SELECT * from rated where HotelID =:hotel');
$database->bind(':hotel', $HotelID);
//echo $database->resultset();
$rows=array();
$rows= $database->resultset(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
//while($rows= $database->resultset());
//while($hotel = $q->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC));
  { 
  echo "<pre>";
print_r($rows);
echo "</pre>";
  echo "<div>'.$rows[LowRate].'<div>";


  };
  ?>
```

So based on the above i can see the array on my page so the query works.
But I want to use the variables in my html like.

```
<p class="price-display-large page-price-text">'.$rows[LowRate].''.rows[PropertyCurrency].'</p>
```

But this does not work.

Comment: PDO wrappers, especially ones that store transient objects like `PDOStatement` as properties are more trouble than they're worth. Unless you're adding significant functionality on top of PDO, I'd steer well clear of writing one

Comment: Oh, also, your main problem is that `Database::query` **doesn't return anything** so you're trying to execute `setFetchMode` on a null object. Enabling error reporting would have pointed this out to you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just replace the harcoded value `'105'` with a reference to `$ratedId`.

```
$database->bind(':hotel', $ratedId);
```

I don't understand why that wouldn't work for you. Include the bind type, if you want something other than what the library function is going to assign.

```
$database->bind(':hotel', $ratedId, PDO::PARAM_INT);
```

(It's likely I entirely misunderstood the question you were asking.)

---

**FOLLOWUP**

I expect `rows` is a multidimensional array, since it looks like a "fetch all" operation has been done. Each row will be an array, but those are all going to be contained in another array.

To see what's in the array, you could do a:

```
var_dump($rows);
```

To get the `LowRate` value from the first row, I think you'd need to refer to it like this:

```
$rows[0]['Lowrate']
```

(I think it's zero based, if not, it will be a [1]. The `var_dump` will show you what it looks like.)

Just because you got an array back, that doesn't mean there's rows in it, it could be an empty set. An resultset with zero rows is a valid resultset, so you really want to check if the row you want is in there or not.

The normative pattern would be to loop through the array of rows, and handle each row individually. For example, using a `foreach` loop.

```
foreach($rows as $row) {
   echo $row['LowRate'];
}
```

Comment: Hi The $ratedID works but I want to get the data from mysql in to aray and use the objects in html.

Comment: i used a fetch row instead of an array as i am pulling only one row of data anyway.This solved the problem and i dont have to use row[0] like syntax.thank you very much for your help